# SQL: count last equal values

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to solve this problem in pure SQL:
I have to count all the records with a specific value:
In my table there is a column flag with values 0 or 1. I need to count all the 1 after last 0 and sum the amount column values of those records.

Example:

```
Flag | Amount

0    | 5
1    | 8
0    | 10
1    | 20
1    | 30
```

Output:

```
2    | 50
```

If last value is 0 I don't need to do anything.
I hasten that I need to perform a fast query (possibly accessing just one time).

Comment: Is there a column, that defines the order? Without it, this is impossible as there is no intrinsic order in tables (which are actually relations, a special case of sets). And please tag the DBMS and its version this is for, solutions may vary greatly among them.

Comment: Is your example table ordered by amount?

Comment: No, It isn't...

Answer (score 1):

I assumed that your example table is logically ordered by Amount. Then you can do this:

```
select
     count(*) as cnt
    ,sum(Amount) as Amount
from yourTable
where Amount > (select max(Amount) from yourTable where Flag = 0)
```

If the biggest value is from a row `where Flag = 0` then nothing will be returned.

Comment: It Is not sorted by amount

Answer (score 0):

If your table may not contain *any* zeros, then you are safer with:

```
select count(*) as cnt, sum(Amount) as Amount
from t
where Amount > all (select Amount from t where Flag = 0)
```

Or, using window functions:

```
select count(*) as cnt, sum(amount) as amount
from (select t.*, max(case when flag = 0 then amount end) as flag0_amount
      from t
     ) t
where flag0_amount is null or amount > flag0_amount
```

Comment: This was my first solution but I need to solve It with maximum one access to the table since It is very expensive

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution by myself:

```
select decode(lv,0,0,tot-prog) somma ,decode(lv,0,0,cnt-myrow) count
from(
select * from
(
        select pan,dt,flag,am, 
        last_value(flag) over() lv, 
        row_number() OVER (order by dt) AS myrow,
        count(*) over() cnt,
        case when lead(flag) OVER (ORDER BY dt) != flag then rownum  end AS change,
        sum(am) over() tot,
        sum(am) over(order by dt) prog
        from test
        where   pan=:pan and dt > :dt and flag is not null
        order by dt
        ) t 
where change is not null        
order by change desc
) where rownum =1
```